# Solving assignment problem with OR-TOOLS with number of tasks

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I am trying to understand how OR-TOOLS works and wanted to solve the assignment problem but with number of tasks (2 out of 4) as constraints. But my code does not work as expectected.

I have tried:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


costs = [
    [90, 80, 75, 70],
    [35, 85, 55, 65],
    [125, 95, 90, 95],
    [45, 110, 95, 115],
    [50, 100, 90, 100],
]
num_workers = len(costs)
num_tasks = len(costs[0])

# Model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Variables
x = []
for i in range(num_workers):
    t = []
    for j in range(num_tasks):
        t.append(model.NewBoolVar(f'x[{i},{j}]'))
    x.append(t)

# Constraints
# Each worker is assigned to exactly one task.
for worker in range(num_workers):
    model.AddExactlyOne(x[worker][task] for task in range(num_tasks))

# Choosing number of tasks.
for worker in range(num_workers):
    model.Add(sum([x[worker][task] for task in range(num_tasks)]) == 2)

# Objective
objective_terms = []
for i in range(num_workers):
    for j in range(num_tasks):
        objective_terms.append(costs[i][j] * x[i][j])
model.Minimize(sum(objective_terms))

# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

# Print solution.
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    print(f'Total cost = {solver.ObjectiveValue()}')
    print()
    for i in range(num_workers):
        for j in range(num_tasks):
            if solver.BooleanValue(x[i][j]):
                print(
                    f'Worker {i} assigned to task {j} Cost = {costs[i][j]}')
else:
    print('No solution found.')
```

So how do I define a number of tasks to use as a constraint?

I get "No solution found" as output. But I expect that task 0 and task 3 will be selected and output should look like this

```
Worker 0 assigned to task 1 Cost = 70
Worker 1 assigned to task 0 Cost = 35
Worker 2 assigned to task 1 Cost = 95
Worker 3 assigned to task 0 Cost = 45
Worker 4 assigned to task 0 Cost = 50
```

If we assign every worker to only one task and choose two tasks, this should be the optimal solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expected output and the actual output your code produces.  In addition, explain the rationale behind why you feel the actual output is incorrect.

Comment: Your 2 constraints are contradictory, and your model reports status INFEASIBLE.  You limit the worker assignment to exactly one task and then in the next constraint, attempt to force it to be each worker to 2 tasks.  Pick one or the other.  Your description is confusing when you say "2 out of 4 tasks"...  Are you intending to say that either exactly 2 tasks are accomplished or minimally 2 are accomplished?

Comment: I mean that exactly 2 tasks should be chosen that have a minimal cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using [channeling constraint](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/main/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md)

Expressing @AirSquid's idea in CP-SAT syntax:

```
task_assigned = [model.NewBoolVar(f"task_assigned{i}") for i in range(num_tasks)]
for task_id in range(num_tasks):
    sum_expr = sum([x[worker][task_id] for worker in range(num_workers)])
    model.Add(sum_expr >= 1).OnlyEnforceIf(task_assigned[task_id])
    model.Add(sum_expr == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(task_assigned[task_id].Not())
model.Add(sum(task_assigned) == 2)
```

This gives the output:

```
Total cost = 295.0

Worker 0 assigned to task 2 Cost = 75
Worker 1 assigned to task 0 Cost = 35
Worker 2 assigned to task 2 Cost = 90
Worker 3 assigned to task 0 Cost = 45
Worker 4 assigned to task 0 Cost = 50
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it later. But the result looks as expected

Comment: I prefer the enforced version (this one) over the bigM version

Comment: @LaurentPerron  I think it is all the same when it ends up in the solver's hands...  Is that true?  Big M, disjunction, or ortools wrapper `OnlyEnforceIf` will all translate into (mostly) equivalent problem expressions for the appropriate solver.  (I'm not objecting to or advocating for any preference...  Just trying to educate myself on some of ortools syntax)

Comment: Yes, we will recognize bigM and create enforcement literals. Then recreate smaller bigM in the optional linear relaxation. It is just that with enforced linear, it is easier to write boolvar <=> var == constant

Answer (score 2):

wrt my comment above, I think you are trying to achieve this:

"exactly 2 out of the 4 tasks are assigned"

And you allow multiple workers to participate in any task, so you have an 'or' condition where either worker 2 or worker 3 or workers 2, 3, and 4 could accomplish a task.  You need a "binary answer" to whether the task is done *at all*.  So, you need to introduce a binary "helper" variable to do that.  (There is probably a shortcut within the `ortools` syntax to do this, but it is important to understand the fundamental concept here.)

in pseudocode:

introduce a new binary variable:

```
task_assigned[j]     j ∈ Tasks
```

Then you need 2 constraints, one to satisfy your requirement of 2 tasks and one to link to worker assignments

```
sum(task_assigned[j] for j in Tasks) == 2

for j in Tasks:
    task_assigned[j] * max_possible_workers_per_task <= sum(x[i][j] for i in Workers)
```

where `max_possible_workers_per_task` is the upper limit of workers/task (perhaps just the number of workers, 5).  This is a 'Big M' Constraint.

Note:  you could also tinker with first constraint and make it a GTE (>=) constraint such that *at least* 2 tasks are assigned.  Right now, your objective gives no credit for accomplishing tasks, just keeping cost down.